# HTMLParser in Java

Tags: java, html-parsing

I m using HTML parser Library for java [here](http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net).

I m having a couple of problems , due to less documenation , depite that i suggest HTML parser fast , error prone code than the JSOUP (Jsoup is actually easy to use but easily to be irritated at your code :( )

1. is how could you extract the meta data ,description on such from the HTML page
   2.How you could specifically get a single tag element from the Parsed HTML document

Thankyou !

Comment: Have you tried Tika also? https://tika.apache.org/1.2/parser.html

Comment: Thanks but , i  dont want to use that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the tag "MyTag", you can also search for tag < meta >

```
Parser parser = new Parser();
parser.setInputHTML(MyHTML);
parser.setEncoding("UTF-8");
NodeList nl = parser.parse(null); 
NodeList node_list= nl.extractAllNodesThatMatch(new TagNameFilter("MyTag"),true);
```